# Pi Zero W loses WiFi Connection when streaming video feed from camera

Tags: networking, wifi, pi-zero-w, raspicam, streaming-video

**Background**: Pi Zero W with Raspbian 10 (buster) installed. I have a small script that runs a local flask server that streams the video feed from a NoIR Picam at 480p. [script and process described here](https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/video-streaming-with-flask)

**Problem**: pi loses wifi when streaming the video feed. Doesn't run for more than a few seconds before losing connection and reconnecting after a couple minutes. This problem never occurred at my previous home/router.

**More Info**: Output of /var/log/syslog when pi loses connection and reconnects:

```
Aug  5 11:49:28 atomzero dhcpcd[467]: wlan0: carrier lost
Aug  5 11:49:29 atomzero dhcpcd[467]: wlan0: deleting address <redacted>
Aug  5 11:49:29 atomzero avahi-daemon[283]: Withdrawing address record for <redacted> on wlan0.
Aug  5 11:49:29 atomzero avahi-daemon[283]: Leaving mDNS multicast group on interface wlan0.IPv6 with address <redacted>.
Aug  5 11:49:29 atomzero avahi-daemon[283]: Joining mDNS multicast group on interface wlan0.IPv6 with address <redacted>.
Aug  5 11:49:29 atomzero avahi-daemon[283]: Registering new address record for <redacted> on wlan0.*.
Aug  5 11:49:29 atomzero dhcpcd[467]: wlan0: deleting route to <redacted>
Aug  5 11:49:29 atomzero dhcpcd[467]: wlan0: deleting default route via <redacted>
Aug  5 11:49:29 atomzero dhcpcd[467]: wlan0: deleting address <redacted>
Aug  5 11:49:29 atomzero avahi-daemon[283]: Withdrawing address record for <redacted> on wlan0.
Aug  5 11:49:29 atomzero avahi-daemon[283]: Leaving mDNS multicast group on interface wlan0.IPv6 with address <redacted>.
Aug  5 11:49:29 atomzero avahi-daemon[283]: Interface wlan0.IPv6 no longer relevant for mDNS.
Aug  5 11:49:29 atomzero avahi-daemon[283]: Withdrawing address record for 192.168.1.115 on wlan0.
Aug  5 11:49:29 atomzero avahi-daemon[283]: Leaving mDNS multicast group on interface wlan0.IPv4 with address 192.168.1.115.
Aug  5 11:49:29 atomzero dhcpcd[467]: wlan0: deleting route to 192.168.1.0/24
Aug  5 11:49:29 atomzero dhcpcd[467]: wlan0: deleting default route via 192.168.1.1
Aug  5 11:49:29 atomzero avahi-daemon[283]: Interface wlan0.IPv4 no longer relevant for mDNS.
Aug  5 11:49:30 atomzero dhcpcd[467]: wlan0: carrier acquired
Aug  5 11:49:30 atomzero dhcpcd[467]: wlan0: IAID eb:55:b2:33
Aug  5 11:49:30 atomzero dhcpcd[467]: wlan0: adding address <redacted>
Aug  5 11:49:30 atomzero avahi-daemon[283]: Joining mDNS multicast group on interface wlan0.IPv6 with address <redacted>.
Aug  5 11:49:30 atomzero avahi-daemon[283]: New relevant interface wlan0.IPv6 for mDNS.
Aug  5 11:49:30 atomzero avahi-daemon[283]: Registering new address record for <redacted>.
Aug  5 11:49:30 atomzero dhcpcd[467]: wlan0: rebinding lease of 192.168.1.115
Aug  5 11:49:30 atomzero dhcpcd[467]: wlan0: probing address 192.168.1.115/24
Aug  5 11:49:30 atomzero dhcpcd[467]: wlan0: soliciting an IPv6 router
Aug  5 11:49:36 atomzero dhcpcd[467]: wlan0: leased 192.168.1.115 for 86400 seconds
Aug  5 11:49:36 atomzero avahi-daemon[283]: Joining mDNS multicast group on interface wlan0.IPv4 with address 192.168.1.115.
Aug  5 11:49:36 atomzero dhcpcd[467]: wlan0: adding route to 192.168.1.0/24
Aug  5 11:49:36 atomzero dhcpcd[467]: wlan0: adding default route via 192.168.1.1
Aug  5 11:49:36 atomzero avahi-daemon[283]: New relevant interface wlan0.IPv4 for mDNS.
Aug  5 11:49:36 atomzero avahi-daemon[283]: Registering new address record for 192.168.1.115 on wlan0.IPv4.
```

- power_save is turned OFF
- The script isn't crashing. It worked before, there are no errors, and the process continues after reconnecting to wifi
- wifi was configured via raspi-config, and also manually set in wpa_supplicant.conf (after the problem was already occurring). Initially wifi was configured using /etc/network/interfaces but that has since been removed.
- connection appears stable when not trying to stream the video feed

**What I've tried**:

- deleting and reconfiguring wifi (three different ways listed above)
- rebooting, and rebooting between wifi reconfigurations
- Dis/Reconnecting camera cable
- placing both the pi and the client device closer to the router
- increasing GPU memory allocation

Comment: Does it disconnect if you are not streaming?  Did you try a reboot on the router - most 'home/ISP' routers are a bit of a pain esp if they are the DNS server as well...

Comment: @Andyroo no the connection is fine until it starts streaming. And yes I tried rebooting the router, I forgot to mention that.

Comment: The output of `/var/log/syslog` doesn't help much. That is the normal behavior of `dhcpcd` and `avahi-daemon` when loosing the WiFi connection. Please [edit](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/posts/115921/edit) the question and add the output of this command to it: `journalctl --boot=0 --unit=wpa_supplicant`.

Comment: I have the same problem with a new Pi Zero W board I just purchased. Wifi stops the second the camera becomes active and comes back after usage. It's very easy to reproduce using raspivid.